# Count number of lines inside polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop

How to count the number of lines that are inside a polygon?

[image]

The methods I have tried don't solve the problem because they either count the FID of the line instead of the segment or cut the line at its intersection.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Whats your method?

Comment: For questions seeking help with code (you have an ArcPy tag) you should present a code snippet to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I removed the arcpy tag. I understand that there are rules here but, in my opinion, it's quite tough to put it on hold just because one doesn't choose the right tags. And without giving the chance to correct the mistake.

Comment: Use the 'Intersect' tool.  Intersect the polygon and line datasets.  This will give the results you need (3 green and 3 red lines).

Answer (score 6):

For your special case you would first clip the lines to the polygon and transform them afterwards from multipart to singlepart features. After these two steps you end up with your desired object count. But be careful if your logic fits to all your data as it is quite special due to self intersections.